# In Magento 2.1.5, is there a way to render a widget within a template by its ID?

Tags: widget, magento2

I would like to render a widget in my template by its ID, just like I have with blocks:

```
echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_name')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will help you.
**For Display Type = All Product Widget**

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget")->setDisplayType("all_products")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

**For Display Type = New Product Widget**

```
     <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget")->setDisplayType("new_products")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```